# iPhone PLIST File Upload coming out Binary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone app built in Objective C that uploads a PLIST file from the iPhone to a server.  Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes the file looks like this

```
bplist00Ú .....
```

I found out that this is apparently a binary PLIST, but I can't figure out why that would happen.

Any thoughts?

```
NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 

// Location ID doesn't seem to be correct here - always 0?
NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString string];
[urlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/app/iphone/submitjob/upload?jid=%i&mid=%@&lid=%i", delegate.jobInProgress.jobID, delegate.memberID, [[delegate.jobInProgress.plist objectForKey:@"locationID"] intValue]]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
returnString = [returnString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: please post the code that writes out the binary. it will give us something to go on

Comment: Well that's the odd part, the PLIST comes in the app as XML.  I can post the code that uploads the PLIST though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you uploading an existing .plist that is in the bundle?  Because all .plist in the project are convert to binary format.  I would create any .plist that you are uploading to your server from scratch using [CFPropertyListWrite](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html) and setting the format to `kCFPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0`.  Then upload the resulting file to your server.  That way, you are not depending on the format that it's in the bundle.

Comment: AHHH  I think that's what it is.  I have the PLIST in the bundle already, but what I can't figure out is why they usually come through in XML format.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and add some of the code where you load the .plist to sent it to the server.  Therefore with more eyes looking at the code we could provide a better answer.

Comment: I posted the code.  My bounty will run out today, and I believe you have provided the right answer, but any insight on the code would be nice.

Comment: I will give a more detail look when I reach home in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

I think Xcode often converts the Info.plist file into binary format.  It might depend on what sort of build you are doing, e.g. I have a vague memory that signed builds might need a binary PLIST instead of an XML one, I'm not sure though.

FYI, you can use `plutil` to convert a PLIST to and from binary/XML format:

```
plutil -convert xml1 <binary plist file>
plutil -convert binary1 <XML plist file>
```

You can also use PlistBuddy to manipulate PLIST files, using the `-x` option to write it out as XML.  Here's the man page for PlistBuddy:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html

Comment: The interesting thing is that most of the plist files come in as XML already, but some come in as Binary.  I can't figure out what would make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

There's setting "Property List Output Encoding" in Project/Target Build Settings which controls output format for most plists: binary, xml, same-as-input.

And you can also modify type for particular file. In XCode 3.x under Get Info in context menu. In XCode 4 - left panel "Utilities" - File Inspector - Identity and Type - File Type. 
Pure XML type should preserve file as is in all situations.

If you generate plists from code you can use `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0` format instead of `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` for xml output.

Comment: Posted code is for uploading plist from application documents directory to the server. It's still unclear how you put plist file to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

the plist can have three formats, plain text, xml or a binary format.

the binary format has the advantage that it can be much faster processed when loading or saving on the iphone.

I don't think you can control which format is used, depending on what function you use to write, but there are scripts in perl, python or php that can also parse binary plists.

for python look at https://github.com/farcaller/bplist-python

for php look at https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList